# Detect multiple filetype in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, file-type

I search to detect in a string if the content is just a text or if it's an image URL. I base my detection with the filetype, but I don't know how to detect multiple file types…

```
var wrapper = (content.indexOf(".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".bmp") != -1)
                ? '<img src="' + content + '" />'
                : '<span>' + content + '</span>';
```

I know this syntax for indexOf is wrong, but in an ideal, that's what I search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a cleaner solution - no slice/indexOf or anything like that involved: It tests all elements of the ext array against the content and returns the elements, which match. Since there should be only one match, you just need to check the first element.

```
var content = "/test.png",
    ext = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".bmp"],
    res,wrapper;

res = ext.filter(function(el){return content.match(el)});

wrapper = res[0] ? '<img src="'+content+'" />' : '<span>'+content+'</span>';
```

See [Array.prototype.filter on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more explanation. As with Fabrizio's solution this solution might break too, if you have filenames with several `.` `/test.png.jpg` (whatever the reason for that might be).

Comment: well yes, it should;) However, same as with indexOf you need to be careful with compatibility - it's supported from IE9 on, but you can use the Shim mentioned in the MDN article for older IE versions.

Answer (score 1):

just use indexOf over an array

```
var wrapper = ([".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".bmp"].indexOf(content.slice(-4)) > -1)
                ? '<img src="' + content + '" />'
                : '<span>' + content + '</span>';
```

`content.slice(-4)` return last 4 characters of `content`

On older browser you will need to use a polyfill for `indexOf`,
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: this will not work, since content is not the file extension but the whole uri.

Comment: @Christoph just sliced the string to get last 4 characters

Comment: Yay! Exactly that. It was too simple but I don't know this possibility. Thank you!

Comment: `content.slice(-4)` -> `.jpeg` = "meeeeep"

Comment: `".jpeg".indexOf('jpeg');` works anyway; or use a regular expression to match a substring from last `.`

Comment: what if you have extensions with only two letters? `.gz` for example? :-D

Comment: well in that case I already suggested a different approach on my last comment. :)